# Method delegation in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var myWidget = $('#myWidget');
```

and calls like this elsewhere:

```
myWidget.hide();
myWidget.slideToggle();
```

These work of course because jQuery adds these methods.

Now, let's say I'm doing some refactoring to make myWidget a proper object with its own custom methods and state:

```
var myWidget = (function() {
    // private stuff
    var actualJQueryObject = $('#myWidget');
    return {
        publicMethod: function() {...},
        // MAGIC!
    }
})()
```

but I want to have all the calls that expect a jQuery object, which are all around my code, to *still work even though myWidget is no longer a jQuery object*, because myWidget knows how to delegate these calls to actualJQueryObject.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also [extend](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend) your jQuery object, with another object that has your custom methods:

```
var myWidget = function() {
    // private stuff
    var actualJQueryObject = $('#myWidget');

    var extensionMethods = {
        publicMethod: function() { alert('public method!'); }  
    }
    return $.extend(actualJQueryObject, extensionMethods);
}();
```

Just be careful with the name of your *extension methods*, to not clash with any other jQuery defined function.

You can try the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ukize/edit).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I knew there must have been some really basic way to do what I wanted with inheritance.

Comment: Check my function i listed below just in case you need multiple namespaces.

Comment: Maybe at this point though, people would want to start looking at jQuery.sub() which came out in 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using the original jquery object as a prototype.

```
function wrap(jqObject) {
    function MyNewType() {
        this.changeFontSize = function(a) { 
            this.css({fontSize : this.size});
        };
    }
    MyNewType.prototype = jqObject;
    return new MyNewType;
}
var obj = wrap($('#someitem'));
obj.size = 50;        // obj.size
obj.changeFontSize(); // obj.changeFontSize
obj.hide();           // $.hide
obj.fadeIn("slow");   // $.fadeIn
```

Comment: Very nice answer; I'll be using it.  Is there a way to make the creation look like normal object construction, i.e. "var obj = new Wrapper($('#someitem'));" instead of "var obj = wrap($('#someitem'));"?  Also it would be helpful to show how to add a wrapper method that wraps an underlying method of the same name, e.g. obj.fadeOut("slow") calls obj.fadeOut, which prints something to console and then calls $.fadeOut.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a plugin that might help you. It's basically a plugin for writing plugins. This dev group post explains it and has some code samples:

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/664cb89b43ccb92c/72cf730045d4333a?hl=en&q=structure+plugin+authoring#72cf730045d4333a

And the source is here:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-plugin-dev/source/browse/trunk/jquery.plugin.js

**EDIT:**

I created a function that has similar functionality to that plugin:

```
jQuerify = function(fn) {
    function plugin() {
        var instantiate = false;

        // check to see if it has any prototyped methods (we only need one iteration to do this)
        for (var i in construct.prototype) {
            instantiate = true;

            break;
        }

        // if there are prototyped methods, return an instance (since an instance's return value won't vary)
        // otherwise just call it using apply so the return value can vary
        return instantiate
            ? new construct(this, arguments)
            : construct(this, arguments);
    }

    function construct(parent, args) {
        // 'this' will not mimic jQuery unless given the length property
        this.length   = 0;
        this.selector = parent.selector;
        this.context  = parent.context;

        // mimic 'this' in jQuery, but for the plugin namespace
        Array.prototype.push.apply(this, $.makeArray(parent));

        // return the constructors return value
        // should be 'this' if you want to chain the new namespace
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // copy all static properties and methods
    for (var i in fn) {
        plugin[i] = fn[i];
    }

    // allow .fn and copy all instance properties and methods; the last part is for IE
    plugin.fn = construct.prototype = plugin.prototype = fn.prototype;

    return plugin;
}
```

This allows you to add custom objects to jQuery as a plugin while using 'this' to refer to the selected objects and also allows you to have an unlimited depth to your namespace:

```
function test1() {
    return this;
}
test1.prototype.getHtml1 = function() {
    return $(this).html();
}

function test2() {
    return this;
}
test2.prototype.getHtml2 = function() {
    return $(this).html();
}

function test3() {
    return this;
}
test3.prototype.getHtml3 = function() {
    return $(this).html();
}

jQuery.fn.test1                   = jQuerify(test1);
jQuery.fn.test1.fn.test2          = jQuerify(test2);
jQuery.fn.test1.fn.test2.fn.test3 = jQuerify(test3);

jQuery(function($) {

    alert($('body').test1().getHtml1());
    alert($('body').test1().test2().getHtml2());
    alert($('body').test1().test2().test3().getHtml3());

});
```